# Autocomplete textbox isn't working in codeigniter

Tags: php, jquery, json, codeigniter

controller: **Welcome.php**

```
<?php
defined('BASEPATH') OR exit('No direct script access allowed');
class Welcome extends CI_Controller {
    function __construct() 
    {
        parent :: __construct();
        $this->load->helper(array('form', 'url', 'captcha', 'email'));
        $this->load->model('Main_tutorial');
    }
    public function index()
    {
        $this->load->view('index');
    }
    public function get_tutorial(){
        $keyword=$this->input->post('keyword');
        $data=$this->Main_tutorial->getrow($keyword);        
        echo json_encode($data);
    }
}
```

model. **Main_tutorial.php**

```
<?php  
class Main_tutorial extends CI_Model  
{  
    function __construct()  
    {   
        parent::__construct();  
    }  
    public function getrow($keyword) {        
        $this->db->order_by('id', 'DESC');
        $this->db->like("tutorial_name", $keyword);
        return $this->db->get('tutorial')->result_array();
    }
}
```

view: **index.php**

```
<input class="search-bg__text" type="text" name="tutorial_name" id="tutorial_name" autocomplete="off" placeholder="search....">
<ul class="dropdown-menu tutos" role="menu" aria-labelledby="dropdownMenu"  id="Dropdowntuto"></ul>
```

**custom.js**

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    $("#tutorial_name").keyup(function () {
        $.ajax({
            type: "POST",
            url: "http://localhost/codeigniter/welcome/get_tutorial",
            data: { keyword: $("#tutorial_name").val()},
            dataType: "json",
            success: function (data) {
                if (data.length > 0) {
                    $('#Dropdowntuto').empty();
                    $('#tutorial_name').attr("data-toggle", "dropdown");
                    $('#Dropdowntuto').dropdown('toggle');
                }
                else if (data.length == 0) {
                    $('#tutorial_name').attr("data-toggle", "");
                }
                $.each(data, function (key,value) {
                    if (data.length >= 0)
                        $('#Dropdowntuto').append('<li role="displayTuto" ><a role="menuitem dropdowntutoli" class="dropdownlivalue">' + value['name'] + '</a></li>');
                });
            }
        });
    });
    $('ul.tutos').on('click', 'li a', function () {
        $('#tutorial_name').val($(this).text());
    });
});
```

In this code I want to create an autocomplete suggestion box using json, codeigniter. Now, When I run the path as well I give into my custom.js file it show me all data in json. But when I write inside the text field it show nothing I don't know what's the problem behind this. So, How can I fix this issue? Please help me out.

Thank you

Answer (score 0):

In your `custom.js` file, `value['name']` must be like `value.name`